# Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; right syntax to use near '3 = ''' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to set up `(int)` in my table country to `up=up+1`. I am trying to match `open_id (PK)` to `$id`.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '3 = ''' at line 1 
>   UPDATE `country` SET up = up+1, 3 = ''

Filename: `models/Select.php`

Line Number: 73

My model:

```
 public function up_votes($id)
 {  
    $this->db->set('up', 'up+1', FALSE);
    $this->db->update('country', $id); 
    $this->db->where('open_id', $id);
 }
```

Comment: You have column named `3` in your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You have **already** added `where` clause.
**2)** Also your `update` is before of your `where`, meaning your query is executing without the `where` clause and hence it is updating all the records.

```
public function up_votes($id)
{  
    $this->db->set('up', 'up+1', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('open_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('country');
                         //   ^^ removed `$id`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
$this->db->set('up', 'up+1', FALSE);
```

to

```
 $this->db->set('up', '`up+1`', FALSE);
```

And also remove `$id` from update query it would be

```
$this->db->update('country');
```

Comment: The problem is it is updating all entries under up(int)

Comment: @saty: and how will that make a difference ??

Comment: I think there is no need of grave accent.